# MS Access combobox column to lookup a third table (multi-dimensional lookup?)

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I have an Access table and form `testResults` with a field that refers to a test in the `tests` table by its foreign key (`id`). I have a combobox for inputting the test since the users obviously can't see the `id`: instead they see the name. This lookup is simply a two column combobox with the first column zero width.

My problem is that there are multiple tests with the same name but different teachers. Teacher is itself a foreign key from the `tests` table to a third table (`teachers`).

How can the combox on `testResults` show a two column list with the test name and the teacher's name? The best I can do so far is the test name and the teacher's `id`.

If anyone can help, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RowSource` of your combobox should be a query that JOINs both tables, then you can use any column you want.

Something like

```
SELECT tests.id, tests.test_name, teachers.teacher_name
FROM tests INNER JOIN teachers ON tests.teacher_id = teachers.id
```

and of course the combobox needs 3 columns.

Comment: Thanks! Not enough reputation to upvote but yes that's it. I actually had already tried selecting both tables it but forgot to specify the inner join: oops :(